# Undefined global variable when returning data generated in a nested function

Tags: javascript, json, global-variables

I have a function that I call which hits an API and returns a `JSON`, which I am calling `getData`. Inside that function is a nested function that processes the `JSON` and saves it to a new variable `processedData` when it's done making the request from the API.

I'd then like to return that processed `JSON`, but the console is telling me it's undefined. I didn't declare the variable so it should be treated as global. Why am I still having this issue?

The code won't work  with the snippet because the API is only local, but `processedData` essentially looks like this: `{'A': '123'}`

```
function hitAPI() {
    var getData = $.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/myroute');
    getData.done(function() {
        processedData = (JSON.parse(getData['responseJSON']['data']));
    });
    return processedData;
 };

var x = hitAPI()
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a promise.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Notice that `getData` already is a promise :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are looking to use `function(response) { … JSON.parse(response).data; }` as your callback. Don't access `getData` in there.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the dupe. Didn't know this was asynchronous so didn't know how to look for that :) could you expand on your code. I don't follow you?